# Convert embed images to linked

Tags: vba, ms-office, ms-word

I'm trying to fix the macro, shown below.

It is intended to convert embed images to linked (via IncludePicture). However, in it's current state, images are added at the bottom of the document. Obviously, it's far from being perfect. Instead, macro should *replace* embed images with the linked ones, one by one, like shown here:

[image]

How to fix it?

**Also, note: Macro should be launched from *another* file. So, you need two documents: one with macro and one with images. It's not good, but it's how it works currently.**

Code:

```
Sub MakeDocMediaLinked()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim StrOutFold As String, Obj_App As Object, Doc As Document, Rng As Range
    Dim StrDocFile As String, StrZipFile As String, StrMediaFile As String
    With Application.Dialogs(wdDialogFileOpen)
        If .Show = -1 Then
            .Update
            Set Doc = ActiveDocument
        End If
    End With
    If Doc Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    With Doc
        ' ID the document to process
        StrDocFile = .FullName
        StrOutFold = Split(StrDocFile, ".")(0) & "_Media"
        .Close SaveChanges:=False
    End With
    ' Test for existing output folder, create it if it doesn't already exist
    If Dir(StrOutFold, vbDirectory) = "" Then MkDir StrOutFold
    ' In case the output folder is not empty. Also, in case the file has no media
    On Error Resume Next
    ' Delete any files in the output folder
    Kill StrOutFold & "\*.*"
    ' Create a Shell App for accessing the zip archives
    Set Obj_App = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    ' Define the zip name
    StrZipFile = Split(StrDocFile, ".")(0) & ".zip"
    ' Create the zip file, by simply copying to a new file with a zip extension
    FileCopy StrDocFile, StrZipFile
    ' Extract the zip archive's media files to the temporary folder
    Obj_App.NameSpace(StrOutFold & "\").CopyHere Obj_App.NameSpace(StrZipFile & "\word\media\").Items
    ' Delete the zip file - the loop takes care of timing issues
    Do While Dir(StrZipFile) <> ""
        Kill StrZipFile
    Loop
    ' Restore error trapping
    On Error GoTo 0
    ' Get the temporary folder's file listing
    StrMediaFile = Dir(StrOutFold & "\*.*", vbNormal)
    Documents.Open FileName:=StrDocFile
    With ActiveDocument
        ' Process the temporary folder's files
        While StrMediaFile <> ""
            .Range.InsertAfter vbCr
            Set Rng = .Paragraphs.Last.Range
            .Fields.Add Range:=Rng, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, PreserveFormatting:=False, _
                Text:="INCLUDEPICTURE """ & Replace(StrOutFold & "\" & StrMediaFile, "\", "\\") & """ \d"
            ' Get the next media file
            StrMediaFile = Dir()
        Wend
        .Fields.Update
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: What is your timezone?

Comment: @peakpeak GMT+2. I'm trying to test and give responses quickly, sorry if it is a bit slow.

Comment: You are not slow. I'm in Sweden. You?

Comment: @peakpeak Finland :)

Comment: Kyllä! :)      
You speak Swedish?

Comment: Wow! That was quite of a news! I think what you experience is what is happening in many places on our globe right now. You should not be ashamed. You're not bringing any of this to us, as I am not. All over the world peope are struggling to get it right. I am. You are. Don't give up!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could also parse the XML returned by `Document.Content.XML` to extract all the images. Then update each source with the path of the external image and write back the XML with `Document.Content.InsertXML`.

Writing the XML back automatically adds a linked field which seem to be one of your requirement.
It's faster that working with the clipboard and it doesn't alter the style of the shape. Though, you might need to tweak the code to handle specific cases.

```vb
Private Declare PtrSafe Function CryptStringToBinaryW Lib "Crypt32" (ByVal pszString As LongPtr, ByVal cchString As Long, ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByRef pbBinary As Byte, ByRef cbBinary As Long, ByVal pdwSkip As LongPtr, ByVal pdwFlags As LongPtr) As Boolean

Public Sub Example()
  SaveAslinkedImages ActiveDocument, "c:\temp\myfile-no-img.docx"
End Sub

Public Sub SaveAslinkedImages(Doc As Document, fname As String)
  Dim objXml As Object, binData As Object, binName$, nodes, node
  Dim imgPath$, docDir$, imgDir$, i&, data() As Byte

  Set objXml = VBA.CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")
  objXml.Async = False
  objXml.validateOnparse = False

  ' parse xml document '
  objXml.LoadXML Doc.Content.XML

  ' add namespaces for SelectNodes '
  objXml.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", _
    objXml.DocumentElement.getAttributeNode("xmlns:w").XML & " " & _
    objXml.DocumentElement.getAttributeNode("xmlns:v").XML

  ' create the  media folder '
  docDir = Left(fname, InStrRev(fname, "\") - 1)
  imgDir = Left(fname, InStrRev(fname, ".") - 1) & "_media"
  MakeDir imgDir

  ' iterate each image data '
  For Each binData In objXml.SelectNodes("//w:binData")
    binName = binData.getAttribute("w:name")

    ' get all the nodes referencing the image data '
    Set nodes = objXml.SelectNodes("//v:imagedata[@src='" & binName & "']")

    If nodes.Length Then ' if any '
      ' build image path '
      imgPath = imgDir & "\" & Mid(binName, InStrRev(binName, "/") + 1)

      ' save base64 data to file '
      DecodeBase64 binData.Text, data
      SaveBytesAs data, imgPath

      ' remove the data '
      binData.ParentNode.RemoveChild binData

      ' for each image '
      For Each node In nodes
        ' set id '
        node.ParentNode.setAttribute "id", node.ParentNode.getAttribute("o:spid")

        ' remove o namespace '
        node.ParentNode.Removeattribute "o:spid"
        node.Removeattribute "o:title"

        ' set external image source '
        node.setAttribute "src", imgPath
      Next
    End If
  Next

  ' write back the xml and save the document '
  Doc.Content.InsertXML objXml.XML
  Doc.SaveAs2 fname

End Sub

Public Sub SaveBytesAs(data() As Byte, path As String)
  Open path For Binary Access Write As #5
  Put #5, 1, data
  Close #5
End Sub

Public Sub MakeDir(path As String)
  If Len(Dir(path, vbDirectory)) Then Exit Sub
  MakeDir Left(path, InStrRev(path, "\") - 1)
  MkDir path
End Sub

Public Function DecodeBase64(str As String, out() As Byte) As Boolean
  Dim size As Long
  size = ((Len(str) + 3) \ 4) * 3
  ReDim out(0 To size - 1) As Byte
  DecodeBase64 = CryptStringToBinaryW(StrPtr(str), Len(str), 1, out(0), size, 0, 0)
  If size - 1 < UBound(out) Then ReDim Preserve out(0 To size - 1)
End Function
```

Comment: Maybe you know, is there a way to get rid of "MERGEFORMAT" here? (Actually it is "MERGEFORMATINET").

Comment: I noticed the `MERGEFORMATINET` but couldn't find a way remove it via xml. You could iterate each shape to update the expression in the field.

Comment: Try to iterate over Document.Fields

Answer (score 1):

This is where your code is going astray:-

```
With ActiveDocument
            .Range.InsertAfter vbCr
            Set Rng = .Paragraphs.Last.Range
```

You are inserting a carriage return at the end of the document (which actually inserts a new blank paragraph) and then add a field in that paragraph. Obviously, you want the field somewhere else.

Meanwhile, if you wish to delete the links you should let your code do that. I haven't been able to figure out whether your code makes an attempt in that direction but presume that it extracts the picture's path from the link. So, the link should be located and deleted after giving up its path, and the field inserted in its place.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my attempt. I did make an assumption that the shapes in the document would be a `Inline Shape`. I mocked this up on my computer with inline shapes.

**Important Prerequistes**

I'm using early binding of the `Scripting.FileSystemObject` and the `Scripting.Dictionary`. In order for this to function with no other changes to the code, please add a reference to the Microsoft Scripting Runtime.

**How it works**

The code iterates through each shape in the document chosen and saves each shape  to a local folder. Once each shape is saved the shape is then deleted. From here the filename *(key)* and the range *(value)* of the InlineShape is saved into a dictionary. After this process has been done for each shape, the field with the `INCLUDEPICTURE` details are added by iterating through the dictionary to get the values needed.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub SOExample()
On Error GoTo Errhand:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim FileName        As String
    Dim doc             As Document
    Dim rng             As Range ' Used to keep track of where the shape was before being deleted
    Dim shp             As Word.InlineShape 'I think you want to iterate inline shapes which generally are pictures
    Dim i               As Long ' Counter
    Dim fso             As FileSystemObject ' used for File Operations/etc
    Dim tmpPics         As String: tmpPics = GetDesktop & "Temp Pics" 'default folder on the desktop for temp storage
    Dim picData()       As Byte ' To hold picture information
    Dim pos             As Variant
    Dim fileNumb        As Long

    'This section was untouched
    With Application.Dialogs(wdDialogFileOpen)
        If .Show = -1 Then
            .Update
            Set doc = ActiveDocument
        End If
    End With

    'Make sure we have an object to work with
    If doc Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    'Get a reference to FSO
    Set fso = New FileSystemObject

    'Delete files or create folder where needed
    If fso.FolderExists(tmpPics) Then
        fso.DeleteFile (tmpPics & "\*"), True
    Else
        fso.CreateFolder tmpPics
    End If

    'Create a dictionary to store the file name and range
    'We need to do one pass through each image and save them, then delete the sheet
    'As we go we are going to add the filename into our dictionary as the key, and -
    'add the range of the remove image as the value. We use that range later to add the INCLUDEPICTURE portion
    Dim mydict As New Scripting.Dictionary: Set mydict = New Scripting.Dictionary

    'iterate each inlineShape...you may need to alter this as I'm unsure if this is the only type needed
    'To be extracted. Sections of code grabbed from:
    'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6512392/how-to-save-word-shapes-to-image-using-vba
    For Each shp In doc.InlineShapes
        fileNumb = FreeFile
        i = i + 1

        'Build a temporary file name for our temp folder
        FileName = tmpPics & "\Image " & CStr(i) & ".emf"

        'Write the file as an EMF file
        Open FileName For Binary Access Write As fileNumb
        picData = shp.Range.EnhMetaFileBits
        pos = 1

        Put fileNumb, pos, picData
        Close fileNumb

        Set rng = shp.Range

        'Add the details to our dictionary for iteration later
        'I'm not adding the text here as, at least for me, adding this field adds another shape
        'On the next iteration, it was trying to apply the same steps...creating what I'm assuming is an inifinite loop
        If Not mydict.Exists(FileName) Then mydict.Add FileName, rng
        shp.Delete
        Set rng = Nothing
    Next

    Dim var As Variant

    'Go through our dictionary, and add the fields into our document
    For Each var In mydict.Keys
        doc.Fields.Add Range:=mydict(var), _
                       Text:="INCLUDEPICTURE """ & Replace(var, "\", "\\") & """ \d"
    Next


CleanExit:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub

Errhand:
    Debug.Print Err.Number, Err.Description
    Select Case Err.Number
        'Add error handler here

    End Select

    Resume CleanExit

End Sub

'A small helper function to get a path to the desktop
Private Function GetDesktop() As String
    Dim oWSHShell As Object: Set oWSHShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    GetDesktop = oWSHShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop") & "\"
    Set oWSHShell = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Hi, Ryan. First of all, thank you for answer. There are several problems, which I see. 1) Images are exported as EMF, instead of more conventional PNG. It's not a big problem itself, though. 2) For some reason, exported images become larger. For example, 100x100 pixels png-file, after export, looks like shown here: https://imgur.com/a/gZ58x (large, blurry, white space) 3) Repeated images (like shown in my original post) exported multiple times. For example, if document contains 4 images, but only two files (green and yellow rectangles), it will be exported as 4 files: https://imgur.com/a/YdDpL

Comment: Direct links: [One](https://i.imgur.com/NI04fen.png), [Two](https://i.imgur.com/KBCdSk6.png)

Comment: Hi there, can you include a copy of this word doc? I'm unable to replicate this issue.

Answer (score 1):

By locating each image and put the link in its position this code will acheive what you want. Note that the original file will be overwritten if you save the modified document. See my comments in the code for more info.
***Code now works for duplicates as well***

```
Option Explicit
Const IMAGEBASENAME = "image"
Const IMAGEEXTENSION = ".jpeg" 'Images in .zip file are all .jpg

Sub MakeDocMediaLinked()
    Dim StrOutFold As String
    Dim Obj_App As Object
    Dim Doc As Document
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim StrDocFile As String
    Dim StrZipFile As String
    Dim StrMediaFile As String
    Dim objShape As InlineShape
    Dim imgNum As Integer
    Dim imgCount As Integer
    Dim imgName As String
    Dim imgNames As New Collection
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim doDir As Boolean

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With Application.Dialogs(wdDialogFileOpen)
        If .Show = -1 Then
            .Update
            Set Doc = ActiveDocument
        End If
    End With
    If Doc Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    With Doc
        StrDocFile = .FullName    ' ID the document to process
        StrOutFold = Split(StrDocFile, ".")(0) & "_Media"
        .Close SaveChanges:=False
    End With
    If Dir(StrOutFold, vbDirectory) = "" Then MkDir StrOutFold    ' Test for existing output folder, create it if it doesn't already exist
    '*
    '* Delete any files in the output folder. On Error Resume Next not used
    '*
    If Dir(StrOutFold & "\*.*", vbNormal) <> "" Then Kill StrOutFold & "\*.*"
    ' Create a Shell App for accessing the zip archives
    Set Obj_App = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    ' Define the zip name
    StrZipFile = Split(StrDocFile, ".")(0) & ".zip"
    ' Create the zip file, by simply copying to a new file with a zip extension
    FileCopy StrDocFile, StrZipFile
    ' Extract the zip archive's media files to the temporary folder
    Obj_App.NameSpace(StrOutFold & "\").CopyHere Obj_App.NameSpace(StrZipFile & "\word\media\").Items
    Do While Dir(StrZipFile) <> ""     ' Delete the zip file - the loop takes care of timing issues
        Kill StrZipFile
    Loop
    StrMediaFile = Dir(StrOutFold & "\*.*", vbNormal)     ' Get the temporary folder's file listing
    Documents.Open FileName:=StrDocFile
    With ActiveDocument
        imgCount = .InlineShapes.Count
        For imgNum = 1 To imgCount
            '*
            '* Get the (next) image
            '*
            Set objShape = .InlineShapes(imgNum)
            '*
            '* Get the original full path of the image
            '*
            imgName = objShape.AlternativeText
            '*
            '* Look for possible duplicate
            '*
            '* Add the ordinal number as the item and the path as the key to avoid duplicates
            '* If we get an error here then the image is a duplicate of a previous one
            '* The ordinal number in imgNames identifies the image to use in the _Media folder
            '*
            i = imgNames.Count  'Current count
            doDir = True    ' Assume no duplicate
            On Error Resume Next
            imgNames.Add imgNum, imgName
            On Error GoTo 0    'Always reset error handling after Resume
            If i = imgNames.Count Then    'Duplicate found, build the duplicate's file name
                StrMediaFile = IMAGEBASENAME & imgNames(imgName) & IMAGEEXTENSION
                doDir = False    'Do not read a new file
            End If
            '*
            '* Get the range where we want the link to appear
            '*
            Set Rng = objShape.Range
            '*
            '* Delete the image from the document
            '*
            objShape.Delete
            '*
            '* Replace the image with a link to a saved disk image in the *_Media folder
            '*
            .Fields.Add Range:=Rng, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, PreserveFormatting:=False, _
                        Text:="INCLUDEPICTURE """ & Replace(StrOutFold & "\" & StrMediaFile, "\", "\\") & """ \d"
            If doDir Then StrMediaFile = Dir()    ' Get the next media file since we had no duplicate this time
        Next imgNum
        .Fields.Update
    End With
    Set imgNames = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, PeakPeak. Thank you very much for answer. It almost work, except for repeated images. Here is [visual explanation](https://i.imgur.com/SKbcnhL.png). Also, it works only with 2 different documents. If I try to replace images in *current* document, Word will hung up. But this second problem is not very serious.

Comment: Hi John, yes, after posting I realized my solution wouldn't work for repeated images. Back to the drawing board ...

Comment: John, you wrote:
- Also, it works only with 2 different documents. If I try to replace images in current document, Word will hung up. -
That was the original job description, that the macro should be run from a different instance than in the document where the images reside.

Comment: Hi! Very interesting. In comparison with Florent's version, your code have some advantages, but also some disadvantages, too. The advantage is simplicity - you don't rely on complex things like `GlobalSize Lib "kernel32"`. On the other hand, if document contains both JPG's and PNG's, both with duplicates, macro isn't enough intelligent to handle this situation. [That's what I mean](https://i.imgur.com/fXYyRQn.png).

Comment: John, on the contrary. I tried with different image formats, .jpg and .png and your code which extracts the images from the .zip file save all images as .jpg. Thats easy to test by inserting a number of different image formats and run until the extraction is finished. Then examine the content of the *_Media folder. There will be only .jpg's. That's what I did to tune my solution.

Comment: Not sure I understand you correctly (I'm not native English speaker), but here is what I have: [Link 1](https://i.imgur.com/q7rbgOs.png). Also I uploaded everything here: [Link 2](https://ufile.io/m7bpa).

Comment: You are correct. Strange thing is that .jpg files in the word document are saved as .jpeg in the .zip file. This is getting messy. I will look into it further tomorrow (Europe)

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to copy the image to the clipboard with `Selection.Copy` and to save it as a `PNG` from there. Then replace the image with an external link with `Document.InlineShapes.AddPicture`.

To handle the duplicated images, hash each image and keep track of the computed code.
I would also rescale the shape before an after to keep the original resolution.

```vb
Public Sub Example()
  SaveAsExternImages ActiveDocument, "c:\temp\myfile-no-img.docx"
End Sub

Public Sub SaveAsExternImages(doc As Document, fname As String)
  Dim sh As InlineShape, rg As Range, docDir, imgDir, imgPath, imgHash
  Dim hDib, scaleW, scaleH, i As Long
  Dim imgPaths As New Collection
  Dim imgs As New Collection

  ' create the  media folder and set the relative directory '
  docDir = Left(fname, InStrRev(fname, "\") - 1)
  imgDir = Left(fname, InStrRev(fname, ".") - 1) & "_media"
  MakeDir imgDir

  ' clean clipboard '
  Call OpenClipboard: Call EmptyClipboard: Call CloseClipboard

  ' select images '
  For Each sh In doc.InlineShapes
    Select Case sh.Type
      Case wdInlineShapeLinkedPicture, wdInlineShapePicture
        imgs.Add sh
    End Select
  Next

  ' handle each image '
  For Each sh In imgs

    ' store/reset the scale '
    scaleW = sh.ScaleWidth
    scaleH = sh.ScaleHeight
    sh.ScaleWidth = 100
    sh.ScaleHeight = 100

    ' copy shape to the clipboard '
    sh.Select
    doc.Application.Selection.Copy

    ' get clipboard as DIB (device independent bitmap) '
    If OpenClipboard() Then Else Err.Raise 9, , "OpenClipboard failed"
    hDib = GetClipboardData(8)  ' 8 = CF_DIB = BITMAPINFO '
    If hDib Then Else Err.Raise 9, , "GetClipboardData failed"

    ' get image hash code from DIB (CRC32) '
    imgHash = GetDIBHashCode(hDib)

    ' save as PNG if hash not already present in the collection '
    If TryGetValue(imgPaths, imgHash, imgPath) = False Then
      i = i + 1
      imgPath = SaveDIBtoPNG(hDib, imgDir & "\image" & i & ".png")
      imgPath = Mid(imgPath, Len(docDir) + 2) ' make relative '
      imgPaths.Add imgPath, CStr(imgHash)
    End If

    ' dispose clipboard '
    Call EmptyClipboard
    Call CloseClipboard

    ' replace the shape with a linked picture and restore the scale '
    Set rg = sh.Range
    sh.Delete
    doc.Application.ChangeFileOpenDirectory docDir ' set relative folder '
    Set sh = doc.InlineShapes.AddPicture(imgPath, True, False, rg)
    sh.ScaleWidth = scaleW
    sh.ScaleHeight = scaleH
  Next

  doc.SaveAs2 fname
End Sub
```

Related functions/procedures:

```vb
Private Declare PtrSafe Function CLSIDFromString Lib "ole32" (ByVal lpsz As LongPtr, pclsid As Byte) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function RtlComputeCrc32 Lib "ntdll" (ByVal start As Long, ByRef data As Any, ByVal Size As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalLock Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As LongPtr) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalUnlock Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As LongPtr) As Boolean
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalSize Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As LongPtr) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32" (Optional ByVal hwnd As LongPtr) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetClipboardData Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Integer) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function EmptyClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function CloseClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GdiplusStartup Lib "gdiplus" (token As LongPtr, cfg As Any, ByVal hook As LongPtr) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GdiplusShutdown Lib "gdiplus" (ByVal token As LongPtr) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GdipCreateBitmapFromGdiDib Lib "gdiplus" (ByVal hdr As LongPtr, ByVal data As LongPtr, img As LongPtr) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GdipSaveImageToFile Lib "gdiplus" (ByVal img As LongPtr, ByVal path As LongPtr, riid As Byte, ByVal cfg As LongPtr) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GdipDisposeImage Lib "gdiplus" (ByVal img As LongPtr) As Long

Private Function GetDIBHashCode(hDib) As Long
  Dim pDib As LongPtr, bmSize As Long, sz As Long
  pDib = GlobalLock(hDib)
  If pDib Then Else Err.Raise 9, , "GlobalLock failed"
  GetDIBHashCode = RtlComputeCrc32(0, ByVal pDib, GlobalSize(hDib))
  GlobalUnlock hDib
End Function

Private Function SaveDIBtoPNG(hDib, filePath As String) As String
  Dim cfg(0 To 7) As Long, clsid(0 To 15) As Byte, pDib As LongPtr, hGdi As LongPtr, hImg As LongPtr
  CLSIDFromString StrPtr("{557CF406-1A04-11D3-9A73-0000F81EF32E}"), clsid(0) ' PNG encoder '
  cfg(0) = 1&  ' GdiplusVersion '
  pDib = GlobalLock(hDib)   ' lock BITMAPINFOHEADER + image bytes '
  If pDib Then Else Err.Raise 9, , "GlobalLock failed"
  If GdiplusStartup(hGdi, cfg(0), 0) Then Err.Raise 9, , "GdiplusStartup failed"
  If GdipCreateBitmapFromGdiDib(pDib, pDib + 40, hImg) Then Err.Raise 9, , "GdipCreateBitmapFromGdiDib failed"
  If GdipSaveImageToFile(hImg, StrPtr(filePath), clsid(0), 0) Then Err.Raise 9, , "GdipSaveImageToFile failed"
  If GdipDisposeImage(hImg) Then Err.Raise 9, , "GdipDisposeImage failed"
  If GdiplusShutdown(hGdi) Then Err.Raise 9, , "GdiplusShutdown failed"
  GlobalUnlock hDib
  SaveDIBtoPNG = filePath
End Function

Private Function TryGetValue(obj As Collection, Key, outValue) As Boolean
  On Error Resume Next
  outValue = obj.Item(CStr(Key))
  TryGetValue = Err.Number = 0
End Function

Private Sub MakeDir(path)
  If Len(Dir(path, vbDirectory)) = False Then
    MkDir path
  ElseIf Len(Dir(path & "\")) Then
    Kill path & "\*"
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, Florent. Thank you very much for answer. I tried to launch it, but it crashes for me. If I add these 2 code blocks in the same order you posted it (related functions/procedures are located at bottom), Word crashes with error **Compile error: Only comments may appear after End Sub, End Function, or End Property.** ([image1](https://i.imgur.com/gtjWRQp.png)). And if I put related functions/procedures at top, it crashes with error **Run-time error '76': Path not found** ([image2](https://i.imgur.com/vx2CsZG.png)). Probably I miss something?

Comment: For the first error, as the description says, you need to place all the `Private Declare PtrSafe` at the top of the module. The second error is because the folder of the path you provided to `SaveAsExternImages` doesn't exist. So either create it manually, or write a function to create it.

Comment: Hm, now it works, but it doesn't **replace** embed images with linked ones. It only **extracts** images to folder, without re-including them back in the document via IncludePicture. (I will try to play with it more, but currently is works like I described).

Comment: You may need to add some other type of shapes in the section commented ' select images '. Saved images are included back with `doc.InlineShapes.AddPicture`, so I don't get what you mean by "doesn't replace embed images", or "without re-including them back". If you meant to have a "linked image field" instead of a "linked image", then simply replace the line adding the image with the one from your example.

Comment: Yes, I meant "linked image field" and now it works (I replaced that line) - thanks again. But, during my testing I discovered that the resulting DOCX file cannot be opened after I closed it. To reproduce: Step 1. I launch your code (without any modifications). Step 2. Word change file from `Test.docm` to `my-file-no-img.docx`. Step 3. Now I try to close and then reopen this DOCX file - and it will be an error. [Here is screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/VYVm5ME.png). Do you have this problem on your computer?

Comment: It seems, this error occurs because DOCX file continue to contain unexpected macro code. The workaround is pretty simple: Instead of just closing or saving (Ctrl-S) DOCX file, press F12 (Save as...). But probably you have some more elegant solution? :)

Comment: No I've not encountered this error. I would try to run the macro from another instance: `Set app = new Excel.Application`, `app.Visible=True`, `Set doc = app.Documents.Open(...)`. Make sure to remove `doc.Application.ChangeFileOpenDirectory` if you are not using it.

Comment: Well, I'll try. Regardless of my success, I will probably mark this question as answer and also accept the bounty. Because (doubtlessly) your answer is the only completely working here, currently.

Comment: Your second answer works too, I know, but I have a small question about this first version. As you suggested early, I slightly changed the code, and now embed images replaced with `IncludePicture` field. Here is the changed part: https://pastebin.com/GnUWrSy3. But I can't understand, why IncludePicture fields are always contain `MERGEFORMAT`, even if I have `PreserveFormatting:=False` in the code?

Comment: I just tried, the "MERGEFORMAT" is only present if `PreserveFormatting` is set to true. If you are trying to keep the original size, simply rescale the underlying shape from the field: `Set imgField = doc.Fields.Add(...)`, `imgField.InlineShape.ScaleWidth = scaleW` ...

Comment: Very strange. Yes, I understand that it could be somehow corrected, but still wondering is it a bug or something else. Can you, please, upload the exact code you tested to [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/)? And also what version of Word you use?

Comment: I too, my version is slightly differs from yours - 16.0.4549.1000. I tested code from pastebin, and "MERGEFORMAT" still exist regardless of `PreserveFormatting` value. Well, this is probably a bug of Word itself.

Comment: Just a thought, could you try to collapse the range before inserting the field to see if it change anything: `rg.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart`?

Comment: Tested it, no, it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

## New solution

### Method

For each `InlineShape` (working in reverse), **if** it's a `wdInlineShapePicture`

1. Copy it to a temporary document
2. Save the temporary document as `.docx`
3. Copy the temporary document as a `.zip` file
4. Extract the contents of the `*.zip/word/media` folder to a temporary folder
5. Move and rename the only file in that folder to the destination folder
6. Delete the shape
7. Create a field that links to the newly processed file, where the shape used to be

### Code

```
Option Explicit

Sub Example()

    MakeDocMediaLinked ActiveDocument

End Sub

Sub MakeDocMediaLinked(ByRef Doc As Document)

' iterate through each image

Dim i As Long
Dim shapeCollection As InlineShapes
Dim tempDoc As Document
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject  ' early binding; add a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime (scrrun.dll)
Dim oShell As New Shell32.Shell  ' early binding; add a reference to Microsoft Shell Controls and Automation (shell32.dll)
Dim currentMediaFileNameSource As String
Dim currentMediaFileNameNew As String
Dim shp As InlineShape
Dim rngToRemove As Range, rngToInsertInto As Range

Const tempDocFilePathDoc As String = "C:\test\temp.docx"
Const tempDocFilePathZip As String = "C:\test\temp.zip"
Const tempMediaFolderPath As String = "C:\test\temp\"
Const destMediaFolderPath As String = "C:\test\images\"

MakePath tempMediaFolderPath ' make the temporary folder in which to store an image, if it doesn't already exist
MakePath destMediaFolderPath ' make the images folder in which to store the images, if it doesn't already exist

Set tempDoc = Application.Documents.Add(Visible:=False) ' create the temp doc, hide it
tempDoc.SaveAs2 FileName:=tempDocFilePathDoc ' save the temp doc

Set shapeCollection = Doc.InlineShapes

For i = shapeCollection.Count To 1 Step -1 ' working backwards through the collection
    Set shp = shapeCollection(i)
    If shp.Type = wdInlineShapePicture Then
        tempDoc.Range.Delete ' clear the temp doc
        tempDoc.Range.FormattedText = shp.Range.FormattedText ' copy the image into the temp doc
        tempDoc.Save ' save the temp doc
        fso.CopyFile tempDocFilePathDoc, tempDocFilePathZip ' copy the temp doc and rename to a temp zip file (will overwrite existing zip)
        oShell.NameSpace(tempMediaFolderPath).CopyHere oShell.NameSpace(tempDocFilePathZip & "\word\media\").Items ' copy the one media file to a destination
        currentMediaFileNameSource = Dir(tempMediaFolderPath) ' get the name of the media file
        currentMediaFileNameNew = "media-" & i & Mid(currentMediaFileNameSource, InStrRev(currentMediaFileNameSource, ".")) ' names the files media-4.jpeg, media-3.png, etc.
        fso.CopyFile tempMediaFolderPath & currentMediaFileNameSource, destMediaFolderPath & currentMediaFileNameNew ' copy and rename the file into the destination folder
        fso.DeleteFile tempMediaFolderPath & currentMediaFileNameSource, True ' delete the temporary file
        Set rngToRemove = shp.Range ' set the range that we will be removing, i.e. the shape range
        Set rngToInsertInto = shp.Range ' set the range that we will be inserting the field into, i.e. the start of the shape range (1)
        rngToInsertInto.Collapse wdCollapseStart ' set the range that we will be inserting the field into, i.e. the start of the shape range (2)
        rngToRemove.Delete ' remove the shape
        Doc.Fields.Add Range:=rngToInsertInto, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, PreserveFormatting:=False, _
        Text:="INCLUDEPICTURE """ & Replace(destMediaFolderPath & currentMediaFileNameNew, "\", "\\") & """ \d" ' 4. add the field, we refer to destMediaFolderPath & currentMediaFileNameNew in the field definition
    End If
Next i

tempDoc.Close SaveChanges:=False ' close the temp doc

fso.DeleteFile tempDocFilePathZip, True ' delete the temporary zip
fso.DeleteFile tempDocFilePathDoc, True ' delete the temporary doc
fso.DeleteFolder Left(tempMediaFolderPath, Len(tempMediaFolderPath) - 1), True ' delete the temporary folder

Set fso = Nothing
Set oShell = Nothing

End Sub

Sub MakePath(ByVal tempPath As String)

Dim fso As New FileSystemObject

Dim path() As String
Dim path2() As String
Dim i As Long

Do While Right(tempPath, 1) = "\" ' remove any ending slashes
    tempPath = Left(tempPath, Len(tempPath) - 1)
Loop

path = Split(tempPath, "\")
ReDim path2(LBound(path) To UBound(path))

i = LBound(path)
path2(i) = path(i)
If Not fso.FolderExists(path2(i) & "\") Then Exit Sub ' if the drive doesn't even exist, then exit
For i = LBound(path) + 1 To UBound(path)
    path2(i) = path2(i - 1) & "\" & CleanPath(path(i))
    If Not fso.FolderExists(path2(i) & "\") Then fso.CreateFolder path2(i)
Next i

Set fso = Nothing

End Sub

Function CleanPath(ByVal tempPath As String)

Dim i As Long
Dim invalidChars As Variant

invalidChars = Array("/", ":", "*", "?", """", "<", ">", "|")

For i = LBound(invalidChars) To UBound(invalidChars)
    tempPath = Replace(tempPath, invalidChars(i), " ")
Next i

CleanPath = tempPath

End Function
```

### After

#### images folder

[image: images folder]

#### document (showing fields)

[image: document]

Comment: Hi, Tigregalis. It almost work, except for repeated images. [Here is screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/i1AoYSt.png)

Comment: Hmm, okay. I think @Florent B.'s xml solution might be the way to go, but I have another solution (not sure how performant it is).

Comment: Hey @johnc.j. , I have completely redesigned the solution, and it should work for any range with `InlineShapes`. The only problem with this solution (if it is a problem) is that it creates duplicate images for each folder. In theory, you could identify images that already exist (using a collection or dictionary) and a hashing function, then fall back to that already-existing image instead of creating a copy, but in my opinion that is outside the scope of this question.

Comment: Tested it. It will not work for document which contains both jpgs and pngs, both with repeats. Test file uploaded here: https://ufile.io/tnx0x

Comment: Hi @johnc.j., I tested your test document and it works fine as far as I can see.

Comment: Added images to the post

Comment: Probably, it is some inconsistency between Word versions? On one it works, on another will not? I use Word 2016, build 16.0.4549.1000. On this test document, the macro crashes (to be sure, I tested it again after your comments), giving me this error message: **Run-time error '4605': This method or property is not available because the Clipboard is empty or not valid.** Here is detailed image: https://i.imgur.com/D89w3RF.png.

Comment: I have a feeling that in your case, the clipboard just doesn't have the data in it yet when you try to paste. Maybe try adding `DoEvents` just before the line that crashes?

Comment: @johnc.j. Actually, I have a better idea. Let's bypass the clipboard entirely, using `Range.FormattedText = Range.FormattedText`, instead of `Range.Copy: Range.Paste`. Updated code to reflect changes.

Comment: Yes, this new version works :) The only little problem with the exported images is that they are duplicated. For example, here are the exported images from the posted above test file - https://i.imgur.com/dtSNZeu.png

Comment: Yes, I know, I mentioned that in the [previous comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46436132/convert-embed-images-to-linked/46529982?noredirect=1#comment80127813_46529982), as well as the outline of a solution.

Answer (score 1):

John, yet another attempt. Runs fine with your test document and my docs as well.

Made the code 2 pass.
I found that sometimes original .jpg files will be saved as .jpeg files in the .zip file
Also sometimes .png files will be saved in .zip file as .jpeg. 
I did not put any effort on finding out why. Instead I modified my code to cope with this fact.
Here is the result which will handle any number of duplicates.

```
'********************************************************************
'* Replace original images with links to locally extracted images
'* Ver. 1.02 2017-10-04 peakpeak
'*
Option Explicit
Const IMAGEBASENAME = "image"
Const JPEG = "jpeg"
Const JPG = "jpg"
Sub MakeDocMediaLinked()
    Dim Doc As Document
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim StrOutFold As String
    Dim StrDocFile As String
    Dim StrZipFile As String
    Dim imgName As String
    Dim StrMediaFile As String
    Dim imgNum As Integer
    Dim imgCount As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim ordinalNum As Integer
    Dim imgOrdinals As New Collection
    Dim objShape As InlineShape
    Dim Obj_App As Object

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With Application.Dialogs(wdDialogFileOpen)
        If .Show = -1 Then
            .Update
            Set Doc = ActiveDocument
        End If
    End With
    If Doc Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    With Doc
        StrDocFile = .FullName    ' ID the document to process
        StrOutFold = Split(StrDocFile, ".")(0) & "_Media"
        .Close SaveChanges:=False
    End With
    If Dir(StrOutFold, vbDirectory) = "" Then MkDir StrOutFold    ' Test for existing output folder, create it if it doesn't already exist
    '*
    '* Delete any files in the output folder. On Error Resume Next not used
    '*
    If Dir(StrOutFold & "\*.*", vbNormal) <> "" Then Kill StrOutFold & "\*.*"
    ' Create a Shell App for accessing the zip archives
    Set Obj_App = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    ' Define the zip name
    StrZipFile = Split(StrDocFile, ".")(0) & ".zip"
    ' Create the zip file, by simply copying to a new file with a zip extension
    FileCopy StrDocFile, StrZipFile
    ' Extract the zip archive's media files to the temporary folder
    Obj_App.NameSpace(StrOutFold & "\").CopyHere Obj_App.NameSpace(StrZipFile & "\word\media\").Items
    Do While Dir(StrZipFile) <> ""     ' Delete the zip file - the loop takes care of timing issues
        Kill StrZipFile
    Loop
    StrMediaFile = Dir(StrOutFold & "\*.*", vbNormal)     ' Get the temporary folder's file listing
    Documents.Open FileName:=StrDocFile
    With ActiveDocument
        imgCount = .InlineShapes.Count
        '*
        '* Pass 1, collect ordinal numbers for all unique images
        '*
        ordinalNum = 1
        For imgNum = 1 To imgCount
            Set objShape = .InlineShapes(imgNum)
            imgName = objShape.AlternativeText  'Contains the full path to the original inserted image
            i = imgOrdinals.Count               'Current count of image ordinals
            On Error Resume Next
            imgOrdinals.Add ordinalNum, imgName    'Error if duplicate
            On Error GoTo 0                 'Always reset error handling after Resume
            If i <> imgOrdinals.Count Then ordinalNum = ordinalNum + 1 'Ordinal added
        Next imgNum
        '*
        '* Pass 2, replace images with links
        '*
        For imgNum = 1 To imgCount
            '*
            '* Get the (next) image
            '*
            Set objShape = .InlineShapes(imgNum)
            '*
            '* Get the original full path of the image
            '*
            imgName = objShape.AlternativeText  'Contains the full path to the original inserted image
            '*
            '* Original extension and extension in the .zip file might differ due to internal algorithms in Word
            '* Get the image file name in *_Media folder based on its ordinal number and regardless of original extension
            '*
            StrMediaFile = Dir(StrOutFold & "\" & IMAGEBASENAME & imgOrdinals(imgName) & ".*", vbNormal)
            '*
            '* Get the range where we want the link to appear
            '*
            Set Rng = objShape.Range
            '*
            '* Delete the image from the document
            '*
            objShape.Delete
            '*
            '* Replace the image with a link to a saved disk image in the *_Media folder
            '*
            .Fields.Add Range:=Rng, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, PreserveFormatting:=False, _
                        Text:="INCLUDEPICTURE """ & Replace(StrOutFold & "\" & StrMediaFile, "\", "\\") & """ \d"
        Next imgNum
        .Fields.Update
    End With
    Set imgOrdinals = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: It works when all inserted images are jpgs. But if we have mixed pngs and jpgs it document, the result will be messed. [Test file](https://ufile.io/pbamj).

Comment: Try this version

Comment: It works, finally! :) I will test more, but currently I don's see any problems.

Comment: Be aware that `InlineShape.AlternativeText` is not documented as returning the path of the image. It returns an empty string with Word 2016.

Comment: I actually use Word 2016!

Comment: I use word 2016 mso 16.0.7571.7095 32 bit, the `AlternativeText` is always empty for an image from the clipboard or inserted from the ribbon.

Comment: Ok, I understand you are angry with me.

Comment: @peakpeak, my comment is just a piece of information which may be relevant to the OP. It's not intended to diminish the value of your solution. You shouldn't take it personally, but with good will as a way to improve your answer, or you could simply ignore it. Either way, I'm not going to get angry, I would even recommend your solution if you had found a reliable way to get the path or name of the image from the Shape.

Comment: `AlternativeText` is always empty for me too. Word 2010.

Comment: @peakpeak Unfortunately, Florent's second comment was correct. It works fine for images which were copied from file manager (Ctrl-C in file manager, Ctrl-V in Word), but fails to correctly work with images, which were inserted via clipboard or via ribbon. As usually, I uploaded a test file: https://ufile.io/bpge5. And here is screenshot with current result: https://i.imgur.com/QhuEuA5.png. I use Word 2016, build 16.0.4549.1000.